# How to use NodeReferences in CypherFluentQuery?

Tags: neo4j, cypher, neo4jclient

I've been experimenting with Neo4J and the text queries work just fine. Then I switched to the Neo4JClient in .Net and now I want to use the CypherFluentQuery, but for some really weird reason the query generated does not include the node ids, but only the placeholders like {p0},p{1}...)
what am I missing?

Below an example of my simple query:

TEXT QUERY (WORKING FINE):

```
string textQuery = "START user=node(9,7,8,10,11) " +
"MATCH user-[:is_friend_of]->isfriendof " +
"RETURN user.name as user,isfriendof.name as IsFriendOf";

CypherQuery query = new CypherQuery(textQuery,
new Dictionary<string, object>(),
CypherResultMode.Projection);
var nodes = client.ExecuteGetCypherResults<MyNode>(query).ToList();
```

Now the CypherFluentQuery (THROWS EXCEPTION):

```
NodeReference<TestNode> node1 = new NodeReference<TestNode>(9);
NodeReference<TestNode> node2 =new NodeReference<TestNode>(7);
NodeReference<TestNode> node3 = new NodeReference<TestNode>(8);
NodeReference<TestNode> node4 = new NodeReference<TestNode>(10);
NodeReference<TestNode> node5 = new NodeReference<TestNode>(11);


NodeReference [] nodes = { node1, node2, node3, node4, node5  };
var results = new CypherFluentQuery(client)
                                    .Start("user", nodes)
                                    .Match("user-[:is_friend_of]->isfriendof")
                                    .Return<MyNode>("user.name as user,isfriendof.name as     IsFriendOf", CypherResultMode.Projection)
                                    .Results.ToList();
```

The referenced Node Classes are these:

```
public class MyNode
{
    public string user { get; set; }
    public string IsFriendOf { get; set; }
}

public class TestNode 
{

    public string name { get; set; }
}
```

**EXCEPTION THROWN:**

```
Received an unexpected HTTP status when executing the request.

The query was: START user=node({p0}, {p1}, {p2}, {p3}, {p4})
MATCH user-[:is_friend_of]->isfriendof
RETURN user.name as user,isfriendof.name as IsFriendOf

The response status was: 400 Bad Request
```

***UPDATE***
I updated Neo4JClient with nugget and now apparently I can't use ExecuteGetCypherResults, so I guess my question now is more valid than ever :-/

Comment: Hi Jorge, What version of Neo4j and Neo4jclient are you using? For your 'text' version as a workaround you can do: ((IRawGraphClient)client).ExecuteGetCypherResults<MyNode>(query).ToList();

Comment: @ChrisSkardon Thanks Chris, I will try again, too bad that I haven't find out the reason why the CypherFluentQuery  is not working

Comment: If you give the version numbers you're using it might be something to do with that.....

Answer (score 0):

The `{p0}` style placeholders are correct. (See the *Parameters* section of https://bitbucket.org/Readify/neo4jclient/wiki/cypher to understand why they exist).

The 400 error back from Neo4j means that it didn't like the query text that was sent.

In your question, you have truncated the exception message right at the useful part though. We need the response body to see what Neo4j is having problems with, and this comes after the response status.

To debug the query text locally, there are also techniques described at https://bitbucket.org/Readify/neo4jclient/wiki/cypher